# titleize a hyphenated name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails' [`titleize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) method removes hyphens, and Ruby's [`capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method does not capitalize the word that comes after a hyphen. I want something like the following:

```
"mary-joe spencer-moore" => "Mary-Joe Spencer-Moore"

"mary-louise o'donnell" => "Mary-Louise O'Donnell"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Check Titelize implementation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) and from it you can get:

```
"mary-joe spencer-moore".humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
```

will give you => "Mary-Joe Spencer-Moore"

and you can write a function for it in string class, Add to intalizers:

```
class String
  def my_titleize
    humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
  end
end
```

and then from your code:

```
"mary-joe spencer-moore".my_titleize
```

Comment: Thank you @mohamed-stark one more question. Can we use it for more generally, names like O'Brien, O'Connor ?

Comment: Yes, sure you will need to modify the regex to match the charcter after colon to be in regex capture to capitalize it.

Comment: Thanks but, to make clear, could I have that regex or working code for a method to do a `"mary-louise o'donnell" => "Mary-Louise O'Donnell"`?

Comment: `"mary-louise o'donnell".humanize.gsub(/\b([a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
=> "Mary-Louise O'Donnell"` if you still need this @kangkyu

Comment: Why is the gsub portion different from the actual titleize implementation? From the docs `gsub(/\b(?<!['â`])[a-z]/)` and in this answer `gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/)`

Comment: @NickShears the one you are looking at is Rails 4 but this answer was answered for Rails 3 check: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize

Comment: in case, when someone uses other strings than alfanumeric [a-z] like latin signs or umlauts or so on.. ypou can use:

`humanize.gsub(/\b('?[^0-9])/) { $1.capitalize }`

Answer (score 10):

You could also get the desired result by splitting up your string and titleizing the sections separately:

```
"mary-louise o'donnell".split('-').map(&:titleize).join('-')
```

Comment: That does work but after some Benchmark.measure it seems to be 3 times slower than the other method. Well... it doesn't matter much though, as an average of 9.214543926410341e-05s is still very good.

Comment: Yeah, I like the conciseness of this solution. If you Are trying to process gigabytes of text then you might want to use a more optimized less concise solution. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 %q%mary-louise o'donnell%.gsub(/\b([a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
 => "Mary-Louise O'Donnell"
```

However, if you may have input with unexpected capitalizations (e.g. "MARY-LOUISE O'DONNELL") then you will first need to `.downcase`; furthermore, if you may have `nil` values for first and last name, and you're then joining them, then you'll want to `.strip`:

```
[first_name, last_name].join(' ').downcase.gsub(/\b([a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }.strip
```